# Adding a background image to cshtml file website

Tags: html, css, razor

I'm new to coding, just started last week. I've been reading and watching a lot of tutorials and finally decided to make a simple web page. I'm using Visual Studio with ASP.NET.

The problem is, I've tried replicating the things I've read and watched on how to apply a background to my  page but the image still doesn't appear. I think it might be with the "url" or a directory problem that I'm not yet aware of. Any help or tips will be appreciated.

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Welcome";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Maykila</title>
    <style>
        body{
            background-image: url("C:/Users/ADMIN/source/repos/Maykila/Maykila/images/Splash.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        }
        /* Center block of elements */
        .main-block {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        /* Site title */
        .site-title {
            font-size: 3em;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-block">
        <h1 class="site-title">Maykila</h1>
        <!-- Other elements can go here -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried searching the internet for solutions and tutorials on how to do it but I'm afraid I'm still missing something.

Comment: Are you using your browser's dev tools inspect facility? It should help you find problems.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use absolute paths. If you deploy your application to a server or continue development in a different folder on a different machine, it will most likely not be on drive C - or even on windows. In any case, the path will be a different one and what works on your current scenario will then be broken.

But, to your problem: in asp.net core, static files, such as images, scripts and css files are located inside the wwwroot folder of your project. You reference them like this:

```css
body {
    background-image: url("~/images/Splash.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Make sure, to have a copy of your image inside your `wwwroot/images` folder! (You can of course configure other folders to serve static files. Read up in the documentation linked below)

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: oh, thanks! I tried it and it worked!

Comment: Feel free, to mark it this as an answer and this question as solved. And take the [tour] while you're at it. Welcome to Stackoverlow.